# Import objects then iterate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, element-ui

I would like to know if it is possible to iterate over imported objects?

```js
import { Row, Col, Form, FormItem, Icon, Input, Tooltip, Image, Button, Dialog } from 'element-ui'

objects.forEach(object => {
  // do something here
})
```

It gets very long when I import a lot of objects. I don't want to use `import ElementUI from 'element-ui'` neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the whole namespace, then iterate over the keys you want:

```
import * as elementUI from 'element-ui';
const props = ['Row', 'Col', 'Form', 'FormItem', 'Icon', 'Input', 'Tooltip', 'Image', 'Button', 'Dialog'];
for (const prop of props) {
  // do something with elementUI[prop]
}
```

If you want to iterate over *every* property, rather than only a select few, you can use `Object.entries` instead:

```
import * as elementUI from 'element-ui';
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(elementUI)) {
  // do something with key and value
}
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Also, thank you for including the answer for both instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wild card` import and then use `for in` to iterate.

```
import * as objects from 'element-ui'

for(const key in objects) {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted, could you please explain so I can improve the ans .

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe because `obj` will be the key not the object

Answer (score -1):

you mean like this?

```js
import { Row, Col, Form, FormItem, Icon, Input, Tooltip, Image, Button, Dialog } as objects from 'element-ui'

objects.forEach(object => {
  // do something here
})
```